# Gauge Charts/ Pointers - Vega lite

Tags: vega-lite

Is it possible to create gauge charts or pointers over pie/donuts in vega lite. Can you guide me to suitable documentation of the same or help with some hints on how to achieve the same

Comment: some free stuff in javascript and CSS, nothing like GoJS

Answer (score -1):

You are probably looking for [the documentation on circular/donut plots](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/#circular-plots). In particular, you can do something like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Proportion of donuts eaten.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": "Glazed", "value": 4},
      {"category": "Cruller", "value": 6},
      {"category": "Boston Creme", "value": 10},
      {"category": "Sprinkles", "value": 3},
      {"category": "Cronut", "value": 7}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "arc", "innerRadius": 50, "outerRadius": 80},
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal", "title": "Type of donut"}
  }
}
```

If you try that in the [online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor), you'll get:

[image: Donut chart of donuts.]